# Inserting XML data into DB

Tags: asp.net, xml, json

Please give me some ideas about inserting XML data in a database
The info I need to insert is from Facebook. Like User relationship info, workinfo and educatio info. 
I know how to use json and deserialize the info from Facebook
Just inserting the deserilaized data into Db in XMl format is what I am not sure

Thanks for all your help

Comment: The question as stated is very broad and actually encompasses several potential problems. Break the problem down into individual steps and try to solve those separately. If you get stuck, post a question about that particular issue.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a MS SQL database there is a XML data type that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I would create models first which will represent my data which will come from XML file. For Examples;

```
  public class Person {

      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Surname { get; set; }
      public bool IsInRelationship { get; set; }

      //this can go on

  }
```

As you know how to deserialize your XML, assign the values to you model.
After that you have some options here;

- use an ORM system, something like Entity Framework to handle your insert operations
- Create Stored Procedures and work on them
- Insert you data directly by hardcoding you t-sql code.